# How to make Firemonkey XE4 HD application with idThreadComponent to work in OSX?

Tags: macos, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe4

I create new Firemonkey HD Desktop application project. I put idThreadComponent1 from Tool Palette to my Form1. I make OS X as active target platform. I hit F9 and soon I get Debugger Exception Notification:

Project dyld raised exception class EReadError with message 'Invalid property value'.

Breaking here brings to Application.Run;
Continuing gives new Debugger Exception Notification:

Project dyld raised exception class EReadError with message 'Error reading IdThreadComponent1.Priority: Invalid property value'.

Application just does not run on OS X. 
Hint for idThreadComponent says that OS X is one of supported platforms. Is it a IDE bug or something? How do I make it to work?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mac expects the Priority to be an integer, but instead it's given an enumerated type (which works on Windows), and it balks with the error 'Invalid property value'. Seems the only solution is to create component during runtime:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Rtti, System.Classes,
  System.Variants, FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Dialogs,
  FMX.StdCtrls, IdBaseComponent, IdThreadComponent;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
    MyIdThreadComponent: TIdThreadComponent;
    Procedure CreateThread;
    procedure MyIdThreadComponentOnRunHandler(Sender: TIdThreadComponent);
    procedure MyIdThreadComponentOnTerminateHandler(Sender: TIdThreadComponent);
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

procedure TForm1.MyIdThreadComponentOnRunHandler(Sender: TIdThreadComponent);
begin
  ShowMessage('Hello');
  MyIdThreadComponent.Terminate;
end;

procedure TForm1.MyIdThreadComponentOnTerminateHandler(Sender: TIdThreadComponent);
begin
  Caption := 'Thread terminated';
end;

Procedure TForm1.CreateThread;
begin
  MyIdThreadComponent := Form1.FindComponent('MyIdThreadComponent')
    as TIdThreadComponent;
  if not Assigned(MyIdThreadComponent) then
  begin
    MyIdThreadComponent := TIdThreadComponent.Create(Self);
    MyIdThreadComponent.OnRun := MyIdThreadComponentOnRunHandler;
    MyIdThreadComponent.OnTerminate := MyIdThreadComponentOnTerminateHandler;
{$IFDEF MSWINDOWS}
    MyIdThreadComponent.Priority := tpNormal;
{$ENDIF}
{$IFDEF MACOS}
    MyIdThreadComponent.Priority := 1;
{$ENDIF}
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  MyIdThreadComponent.Start;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  CreateThread;
end;

end.
```